# Problem with the enter button from smartphone

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good evening everyone, I have the following code in a vue.

```
<input
                type="text"
                class="search-bar"
                placeholder="Cerca una città..."
                v-model="location"
                @keypress="fetchWeather"
              />

 methods: {
        fetchWeather(e) {
          var key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
          if (key == 13) {
            fetch(
              `${this.base_url}weather?q=${this.location}&units=metric&APPID=${this.api_key}`
            )
              .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
              })
              .then(this.setResults)
              .then(this.reset);
          }
        }
```

Now when I press enter from pc everything works as it should, but from smartphone I have to press enter 2 times to make the call correctly .
. Can you tell me why this happens?